# How to ignore a folder in definition index for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Sublime Text added a new feature to show function definition.

[image: Sublime text definition behavior]

Do you know how to disable "dist" folder from the index?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a setting called `index_exclude_patterns` which can be used to exclude specific file patterns from the index. The default value of this is:

```
// index_exclude_patterns indicate which files won't be indexed.
"index_exclude_patterns": ["*.log"],
```

However it seems this can only specify file patterns, not directory patterns. So things like `"dist"`, `"dist*"`, `"dist/"` or `"dist/*"` do not work.

In this case a workaround is to amend the `binary_file_patterns` setting. The default for this is:

```
// These files will still show up in the side bar, but won't be included in
// Goto Anything or Find in Files
"binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

Files that are binary are not indexed and so won't show up in the definition list.

Adding `"dist/*"` to the list of patterns should fix the problem up for you. Note that if you don't already have a custom setting for this you should probably copy the default first, otherwise things like images won't be considered binary any longer.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Changing the setting `"folder_exclude_patterns"` works for this, although the doc says its function is to control which folders are shown in the sidebar.

Comment: exactly what I wanted +1

Comment: This works, but also removes the path from the sidebar (as stated in the answer). If you don't need to see or work on files in this path at all (for example, auto-generated documentation), this solutions is great. However, if you want to keep the path visible but ignored in `Definitions` and `References` (for example, `node_modules`), @OdatNurd's solution of adding to `binary_file_patterns` list works better.